# using a var in a like statement

Tags: php, sql

I am using a var inside a sql statement, which checks on a field which could have many tags in eg

```
adtags="home, about, article"

$queryVar = 'home'



$bannerName = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select  pic.filename
,       pic.pid
,       fv1.field_value as MovieName
,       fv2.field_value as Adlink
from    ngg_pictures pic
inner join 
    nggcf_fields f1
on      f1.field_name = 'adtags'
inner join 
    nggcf_field_values as fv1
on      fv1.pid = pic.pid
    and fv1.fid = f1.id
inner join 
    nggcf_fields f2
on      f2.field_name = 'adlink'
inner join 
    nggcf_field_values as fv2
on      fv2.pid = pic.pid
    and fv2.fid = f2.id
where   fv1.field_value like '%s'   ",$queryVar));
```

note (fv1.field_value is pulling adtags)

I can get this to work where I can find one instance if adtags only contains one tag, and i removed the queryvar methid - but what I would like to do is search fv1.field_value for the occurance of $queryVar (home or anything thats passed)

I think in order to do this I need to use a wildcard, such as %home%

```
where   fv1.field_value like '%home%'
```

but how do I achieve this when the queryvar is referenced as %s, can I escape this out somehow ?

Thanks

Comment: Use prepared statements, don't put php variables in sql directly it'll make you susceptible to sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Would help to see the whole line of code.
Just put the variable in the string.

```
"where fv1.field_value like '%$queryVar%'";
```

Before that you could do something to avoid possible query injection.

Take only the first word.

```
$queryVar = preg_replace('/\s.*$/', '', $queryVar);
```

Take only letters.

```
$queryVar = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $queryVar);
```

**Answer 2**

Do this before the query:

```
$queryVar = "%$queryVar%";
```

**Answer 3**

Escape with %.

```
where   fv1.field_value like '%%%s%%'   ",$queryVar));
```

Comment: That's great thanks, all working - thanks for the advice on the escaping. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are for matching substrings, for example "%home%" will match "come home", "three home runs" and "homeward bound".

You are looking for the `in` operator, this might be a good starting point:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp